# Retrieve generated JS by the coffeescript client-side compiler

Tags: debugging, coffeescript

I would like to debug the generated javascript by the [CoffeeScript client-side compiler](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts), eg:

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
foo = 0
</script>
```

should generate some JS code like that in my page:

```
var foo = 0;
```

So I can add a breakpoint on in my console.

--

The problem is I can't figure out where this JS is injected on the page.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't used the client-side compiler, but my initial thought would be to add a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement, which should place a breakpoint on any debugger automatically.

Comment: Good luck.  I tried debugging this once and it was a huge pain in the booty.  I never did figure out how to step through the generated code.  I just ended up compiling it myself and including it as a js file in order to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't injected into the page as part of the DOM, like you'd have in a <script> tag but directly loaded into the Javascript engine like it would happen in something like

```
eval("var myFoo = function () {}");
```

Having said that, I worked with Visual Studio 2012 which shows such code in a special node called 'Function code' in the solution explorer while running the debugger, but I haven't been able to find this in Firebug or Chrome. Did you try using the 'debugger' statement as suggested by phenomnomnominal?